# folder createFile folder.createFile(theblob) not returning file object per tech specs?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm taking a blob from a spreadsheet and creating a pdf.  Very simple stuff, EXCEPT that I don't seem to be getting back a file object upon file creation as Google's Tech Docs imply??
 var theBlob = newGSheet.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf').setName("myNewPDF.pdf")
var newPDF = folderX.createFile(theBlob)

According to [google tech docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#createFile(BlobSource)), newPDF should be a file object, which would enable me to do something like newPDF.getId(), so I could reference it later.  Instead, I seem to be getting back the name of the file only?  
  
What am I missing?

EDIT/UPDATE:  Here is a [link to a googlesheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uht_2AYasaIIU2YMtwAT5vZqd9uRZDU90zk9t5SlqaU/edit#gid=0) w a faux form to save to PDF and a button to fire a script to create pdf. Script found via tools > script editor. Would need to authorize to view it.

```
function createPDF1() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
var theBlob = ss.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf').setName("testingPDF.pdf")   
var folderX = DriveApp.getFolderById("root")
var fileX = folderX.createFile(theBlob)
var fileXID = fileX.getId()
Logger.log(fileXID)   
// this was returning the file name yesterday
// as if by magic, TODAY, IT SEEMS TO WORK (?!...)  
}
```

Seemingly by an act of magic, what did not work yesterday when I posted this and futzed with it for 30 minutes now works.  So seemingly no issues now...

EDIT2:  To close this matter out...
when the above wasn't working... this code below was..
which showed it was definently returning the filename instead...
also note, it had to be written out in this long form
   1) checking for hasNext 
   2) then getting it and 
   3) then getting ID to return the id
any attempt to assume it had next or combine .next().getId() didnt work..

```
 var hasNext = DriveApp.getFilesByName(fileXID).hasNext()
 if (hasNext) {
    var newPDF_fileX = DriveApp.getFilesByName(newPDF).next()
    var newPDFID =      newPDF_fileX.getId()
  }
```

Comment: Can you provide the script for replicating your issue? Of course, please remove your personal information.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Hi Tanaike - thanks for reaching out. Added the code in original post. While creating the demo for this, magically it worked. Went back to the production script un-commented the nonworking text and it now works there too.  Something was different yesterday, because the file name would not light up and give me the object properties and methods options as it's doing today. Either 1, a blip yesterday or 2, something got corrected on google side overnight. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for replying and updating it. I'm glad your issue was resolved.